# keep getting errors when import Mapbox sdk

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mapbox

I get an error when I download the mapbox maps sdk file and import package to load the sdk file. Does anyone know how to solve it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcG0k.png)

Answer (score 0):

As it says here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-unity-sdk/issues/1753

If you have an Unity version bigger than 2018, you have to edit these scripts: ARCoreInterface.cs & ARKitInterface.cs, replacing every ARBackgroundRenderer with ARCameraBackground.